# spark dataframe calculated column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning spark (scala) and i am creating a dataframe with derived columns. I am trying to figure out the best practices.

my use case has 2 derived columns which look for another columns for value - 
for example -

```
if (col22 = "USD") then col1 = "US" elseif (col22 = "CDN" the col1 = "CA" else null)
```

another use case is

```
if(col23 = "us" && col100 = "abc") then col2 = "10" else if (col23 = "us" && col100 = "bacd" && col99 is null then col2 = 11 else null)
```

Question - i have written UDF functions for the above mentioned calculations. I am wondering is there a better way of doing this? is writing a udf function is the best practice. i will be using these functions only once in my code.

My Scala code -

```
def udf1 = udf((col22: String){  (col22) match {
    case col22 if (col22 == "USD") => "US"
    case col22 if (col22 == "CDN") => "CA"
    case _ => null  } })

val df1= df.select($"col1", $"col2", udf1($"col22").as("newcol"), udf2($"col23", $"col100").as(newcol2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn(
  "newcol",
  when($"col22" === "USD", lit("US")).otherwise(
    when($"col22" === "CDN", lit("CA")).otherwise(lit(null))
  )
)
```

Comment: is it a best practice to use inline code (in your example) or we should use udf?

Comment: You shouldn't use UDFs unless necessary but in-lining is not a hard requirement either. You can compose SQL expressions like any other piece of code.